# Overlap two Box jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to overlap two `Box` or perhaps is better to use `Row` on this case.

My design is one `Row` overlapped with another one, and I've wrapped it on a `Column`, is that correct?

This is the design, what I'd like to have is the rectangle of the top be the same size of the one below and then move it some pixels as you can see in the image, but they should have the same width but not the same height.

[image]

Is it okay if the hierarchy is :

```
Column 
  Box (the one of the top)
    Row
  Box (the one of the bottom)
    Row (inside there is text and it's all the same align)
```

......

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've faced with this some days ago and I solved it using [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraintlayout).

What I had to do is :

1. Add `implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-beta02"` to `build.gradle`
2. Wrap every `Box` in a `ConstraintLayout { .. }`
3. Inside each `Box` add a `Modifier.constrainAs` to align the `Top` `Bottom` `Start` `End` as you want.
4. If you want the first box be the same `width` as the second one without hardcoding the `dps` you should use [`width = Dimension.fillToConstraints`](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts?hl=ko#9)

> fillToConstraints - the layout will expand to fill the space defined by its constraints in that dimension.

Basic example without hard-coding :

```
ConstraintLayout() {
            val (title, description) = createRefs()
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 28.dp)
                    .background(color = Red)
                    .padding(
                        horizontal = 16.dp,
                    )
                    .constrainAs(title) {
                        top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                        width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                    }
            ) {
                Text(text = "Hello World")
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(end = 4.dp)
                    .background(Color.Magenta)
                    .padding(bottom = 5.dp, start = 8.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 4.dp)
                    .constrainAs(description) {
                        top.linkTo(title.top, margin = 16.dp)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    }
            ) {
                Text(text = "Skizo-ozᴉʞS rules")
            }
        }
```

Now you have to play with the `padding` according to your UI and adapt it, result is something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 12):

This is way using [BoxWithConstraints](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#BoxWithConstraints(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)) and not using fixed width and height:

```
BoxWithConstraints(
    Modifier
        .background(color = Color.Blue)
        .padding(20.dp)) {

    val boxWidth = this.maxWidth
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(boxWidth - 10.dp)
            .background(Color.Red)
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello Android")
    }
    Column() {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
            .height(10.dp)
            .width(10.dp))
        Row( ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(boxWidth)
                    .zIndex(2f)
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
            ) {
                Text("aa", modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Green))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: two boxes same width]

Comment: But I want the one in the top be the same width than the one in the bottom

Comment: @dmastra can you help me on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71502444/compose-two-composables-overlaped-and-constraint-with-them

Comment: Hey thanks your code helped my way of achieving view.

Answer (score 11):

In order for the `Composables` to overlap, you should put them in the same `Box`. Try this out:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.size(width = 300.dp, height = 100.dp)) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .size(width = 200.dp, height = 50.dp)
        .background(color = Color.Blue)
        .align(Alignment.TopEnd)) {}
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .size(width = 200.dp, height = 70.dp)
        .background(color = Color.Red)
        .align(Alignment.BottomStart)) {}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to don't make width and height hardcoded and do it "wrap_content"?

Comment: @StuartDTO Why wouldn't it be possible? Omit the size modifiers.

Comment: So if I omit them they are wrap_content directly? I mean inside of my `Box` I have a `Row` with one Text and inside the other `Box` I have a `Row` with more than 1 `Text` so I want that Box (the below one the one with more `Text`) have the same width as the upper one, because the upper `Box` only contains one `Text` and it will be smaller

Comment: @StuartDTO You'd need to somehow determine the width of the bigger Row. But if you omit the size modifier, the containers wrap around the content, yes.

Comment: I mean... with constraint layout this is easy to do, in theory Compose is way easier than XML maybe I can put an example in ConstraintLayout so you can help me better?

Comment: @StuartDTO One way to solve it would be to calculate the size of the bigger Row and assign that to the smaller Row. I didn't do such thing yet. But if you say that you can do it easily with constraint layout, then do so. Jetpack Compose also has Constraint Layout.

Comment: Can you help me on this one @daniyelp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71502444/compose-two-composables-overlaped-and-constraint-with-them

Answer (score 5):

To have two boxes or any other composables overlap in this way you can use `spacedBy` method for the arrangement, either on a `Row` or `Column` and pass a **negative value**. This is supported by the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement) as well.

For example:

```kotlin
fun OverlappingBoxesPreview() {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy((-30).dp),
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .background(Color.Red),
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(80.dp)
                .background(Color.Green),
        )

    }
}
```

Will produce:

[image]

Comment: This reduces the touch target size though. Any way to avoid it reducing touch target size?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this in many ways,

```
@Composable
fun BoxOverBox() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(200.dp)
                .height(50.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(200.dp)
                .height(50.dp)
                .zIndex(2f)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    translationX = -50f
                    translationY = 50f
                }
                .background(Color.Blue)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to don't make width and height hardcoded and do it "wrap_content"? and btw contentAlignment is not reconized in Box.

Comment: Please see the comment I've post on the other answer to understand it better

Comment: I don't want to add a 200dp and height for the box I want to make it wrap content in terms of width... And the first Box be the same width as the one below even if the text is smaller.

Comment: Can you help me on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71502444/compose-two-composables-overlaped-and-constraint-with-them

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use "matchParentSize" modifier that is avaliabele inside  BoxScope, I mean inside Box composable, that modifer measure other children size except itself when it has join the composable at first time to apply the same size to itself.

you can see this modifier in documentation
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).matchParentSize()