# Box overlay in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a composable (shown in below image) where one box is larger and one smaller box is placed at bottom center of large box and bottom line of large box is passing through center of small box. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlap two Box jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70799640/overlap-two-box-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom layout:

```
@Composable
fun Boxes(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content,
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val largeBox = measurables[0]
        val smallBox = measurables[1]
        val looseConstraints = constraints.copy(
            minWidth = 0,
            minHeight = 0,
        )
        val largePlaceable = largeBox.measure(looseConstraints)
        val smallPlaceable = smallBox.measure(looseConstraints)
        layout(
            width = constraints.maxWidth,
            height = constraints.maxHeight
        ) {
            largePlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            smallPlaceable.placeRelative(
                x = (constraints.maxWidth - smallPlaceable.width) / 2,
                y = largePlaceable.height - smallPlaceable.height / 2
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(widthDp = 420, heightDp = 720)
@Composable
fun BoxesPreview() {
    ComposePlaygroundTheme() {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Boxes(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(128.dp)
                        .background(Color.Green)
                )
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(128.dp)
                        .height(64.dp)
                        .background(Color.Red)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Sample]

Edit: restricting the boxes height, use this

```
@Composable
fun Boxes(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content,
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val largeBox = measurables[0]
        val smallBox = measurables[1]
        val looseConstraints = constraints.copy(
            minWidth = 0,
            minHeight = 0,
        )
        val largePlaceable = largeBox.measure(looseConstraints)
        val smallPlaceable = smallBox.measure(looseConstraints)
        layout(
            width = constraints.maxWidth,
            height = largePlaceable.height + smallPlaceable.height / 2,
        ) {
            largePlaceable.placeRelative(
                x = 0,
                y = 0,
            )
            smallPlaceable.placeRelative(
                x = (constraints.maxWidth - smallPlaceable.width) / 2,
                y = largePlaceable.height - smallPlaceable.height / 2
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(widthDp = 420, heightDp = 720)
@Composable
fun BoxesPreview() {
    ComposePlaygroundTheme {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Column {
                Text(
                    text = "Before",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 16.dp)
                )
                Boxes(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(128.dp)
                            .background(Color.Green)
                    )
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(128.dp)
                            .height(64.dp)
                            .background(Color.Red)
                    )
                }
                Text(
                    text = "After",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 16.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: In column]

Comment: I was able to use other composables by limiting `Boxes` height, but can't it work without providing height explicitly?

Comment: To resolve your issue change the layout to use the sum of the heights (large box height + half small box height), I'll update the response.