# How to implement this layout using box composable in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTERf.png)

As you can see in the layout, I want to overlay the smaller box over the edge of the bigger one.
I tried implementing it on my own, but all I was able to do was to overlay the smaller one across the edge of the bigger one and not above the edge.

I was trying to implement it like this, but I guess I'm just not giving the correct arguments in the offset modifier:

```
Box {
        Card(
            modifier= Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(300.dp)
        ){

        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(100.dp)
                .height(100.dp)
                .background(Color.Blue)
                .align(Alignment.TopStart)
                .offset(x=0.dp ,y=40.dp)
        )
    }
```

Comment: In Compose, the order of modifiers often matters. If you place `.offset` before `.background`, the offset should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to Box you could use a custom Layout

```
@Composable
fun OverlappingBoxes(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content,
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val largeBox = measurables[0]
        val smallBox = measurables[1]
        val looseConstraints = constraints.copy(
            minWidth = 0,
            minHeight = 0,
        )
        val largePlaceable = largeBox.measure(looseConstraints)
        val smallPlaceable = smallBox.measure(looseConstraints)
        layout(
            width = constraints.maxWidth,
            height = largePlaceable.height + smallPlaceable.height / 2,
        ) {
            largePlaceable.placeRelative(
                x = 0,
                y = 0,
            )
            smallPlaceable.placeRelative(
                x = - smallPlaceable.width / 2, // overlap by exactly half the sise of second box x axis wise
                y = largePlaceable.height / 2 - smallPlaceable.height / 2 //center with y axis
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BoxOverlap(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    OverlappingBoxes(modifier = modifier.size(300.dp)) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(300.dp)
                .background(Color.Green)
        ) {
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                .background(Color.Blue)
        ) {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

In case you want the second box offset based on percentage

```
val percentageFromTop = 0.3f // 30% from the top
val yOffset = (largePlaceable.height * percentageFromTop).roundToInt()
smallPlaceable.placeRelative(x = - smallPlaceable.width / 2,y = yOffset - smallPlaceable.height / 2
            )
```

There are other answers where constraint layout is used [Overlap two Box jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70799640/overlap-two-box-jetpack-compose). But if you want to go with percentage you can use custom layout